# InvalidOperationException when enumerating through a list of results to provide multiple textbox's with text

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a data entry form with many textbox's and some dropdowns for the user to input data. When the user selects a "Location" from the dropdownlist, they can click a button on top of the form to view a popup with more details according to that location. The data successfully automates when the popup loads but when the user tries to close the popup and continue with the main form, an unhandled exception occurs for the system.InvalidOperationException. The error specifically occurs because "The collection I'm Enumerating through has been changed". Although I'm not changing anything I guess something behind the scenes is happening, here is my code to retreive the data:

```
        string postalCode;
        string phone1;
        string phone2;
        string supervisor;

        var ObjectContext = new ObjectContext();

        var qry = (from i in ObjectContext.TableLocation
                   where i.LocationName == LocationValue
                   select i).ToList();

        foreach (var data in qry)
        {
           postalCode = data.postalCode;
           phone1 = data.phoneNumber1;
           phone2 = data.phoneNumber2;
           supervisor = data.supervisor
        }

        txtPostalCode.Text = postalCode;
        txtPhone1.Text = Phone1;
        txtPhone2.Text = Phone2;
        txtSupervisor.Text = supervisor;
```

The LocationValue is linked to a Public variable that the parent form fills with whatever is selected in the location dropdownlist:

```
        public string CountyValue
        {
            get { return txtCountyName.Text; }
            set { txtCountyName.Text = value; }
        }
```

Is there a better way to enumerate through this list of values and supply them to textbox.text? I have tried everything to fix this error.

*EDIT*
Also all my database columns are Varchars so there was no need to convert data types.

And I only get this error when I deploy my app via ClickOnce to clients PC.

Comment: Please show the body of your foreach loop.

Comment: Create a `string` instance before the `foreach` line, add all data to it and set `textbox.Text` after the loop. See if it helps.

Comment: Tried that too but it basically accomplished the same task with more code and the same exact error :/

Comment: Have you realized that you are setting multiple times the postalCode, phone1, phone2 and supervisor variables? You are losing the previous values, I don't get the point of your foreach loop. Also, the error seems like a DataBinding issue, maybe you should show more code.

Comment: How am I losing the original value when I'm just assigning the variable a value then assigning the variable to fill the textbox.text? This is what @AVIDeveloper suggested and it works the same way. I'm not having any problems getting the data, I'm having problems when i close the popup that is receiving the data.

Comment: ok, so... you are iterating over a List in order to get a single value?

Comment: No, A single row of data that is associated with the location that the user selects.

Comment: So TableLocation.LocationName is a unique column, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, that Location is a single value, and there is no need to create a List. So that means you can avoid iterating over a list, and do this instead:

```
var ObjectContext = new ObjectContext();

    var details = ObjectContext.TableLocation
                    .First(x => x.LocationName == LocationValue)
                    .Select(x => 
                            new { 
                                PostalCode = x.postalCode,
                                Phone1 = x.phoneNumber1,
                                Phone2 = x.phoneNumber2,
                                Supervisor = x.supervisor
                            });

txtPostalCode.Text = details.PostalCode;
txtPhone1.Text = details.Phone1;
txtPhone2.Text = details.Phone2;
txtSupervisor.Text = details.Supervisor;
```

**ADDED:**
Also check this [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), according to it, there are several scenarios where ShowDialog() could throw an InvalidOperationException, that are unrelated to LINQ-to-SQL or EF.
**ADDED:** From that MSDN article it says this:

> When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close
>   button (the button with an X at the upper-right corner of the form)
>   causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set
>   to DialogResult.Cancel. Unlike non-modal forms, the Close method is
>   not called by the .NET Framework when the user clicks the close form
>   button of a dialog box or sets the value of the DialogResult property.
>   Instead the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a
>   new instance of the dialog box. Because a form displayed as a dialog
>   box is hidden instead of closed, you must call the Dispose method of
>   the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

Comment: Well I fixed it, apparently it works when i open the form like this:

        numsPopup.ShowDialog();

but it gives a System.InvalidoperationException error like this:

        numsPopup.Show(This);

I'm not sure why it does this though?

Comment: What is the entire stack trace?

Comment: Wow it all makes sense now, Thanks for the article! It's weird that it threw an error when i deploy it but never on my development pc.

Answer (score 0):

memoize items(.ToArray()) before collection iterations

```
    var qry = (from i in ObjectContext.TableLocation.ToArray() 
               where i.LocationName == LocationValue 
               select i).ToList();
```

Comment: This also works but let me see if it works when i deploy it to a client pc (This is my problem).

Comment: Even when putting it to an array it still says that "Collection was modified, Enumeration may not Execute"